# Binary Tree segmentation fault

Tags: c

Here i have written a code which inserts numbers in Binary tree. But it gives segmentation fault error. 
And also it says " note: expected ‘struct tree *’ but argument is of type ‘struct node *’" in line 8. 
Here is the code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct tree{
  int data;
  struct tree *left;
  struct tree *right;
};

struct tree* insert(struct tree* node, int data)
{
  if(!node){
    node=malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    node->data=data;
    node->left=node->right=NULL;
    return node;
  }
  else {
    if(data>node->data){
     node->right= insert(node->right,data);
     return node;
    }
    else{
     node->left= insert(node->left,data);
    }  
 return node;
  }
}
printtree(struct tree* node)
{
  if(node){
      printf("%d",node->data);
  }
      printtree(node->left);
      printtree(node->right);

} 
main()
{
 int i,n;
 struct tree *NODE;
 NODE= insert(NODE,5);
 NODE= insert(NODE,3);
 NODE= insert(NODE,8);
 printtree(NODE);
}
```

Comment: Where is `struct node` defined?

Comment: Try compiling with warnings for a start to see what's gone wrong that you can fix straightaway.

Comment: Too many errors. As Brett Hale points out, `struct tree *node` is not initialised, `struct tree *treenode` is not used anywhere, and I also believe that in the structure definition,both `struct node` should be `struct tree`

Comment: Now that you've edited your question to include a supplied answer, no one has any idea what the question was, or why you were getting an error. The right thing to do is [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that supplied this code.

Answer (score 4):

You use `if( node )` but better to use `if( node != NULL )`

You use `if( !node )` but better to use `if( node == NULL )`

It make code more readable.

You have so many mistakes - so ... I make it in my way (my code formating, etc.).

`printtree(node->left); printtree(node->right);` was outside `if( node != NULL ){}` so it try to get `NULL->left` and `NULL->right`

Tested - code works.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct tree{
  int data;
  struct tree *left;
  struct tree *right;
};

struct tree* insert(struct tree* node, int data)
{
    if( node == NULL ) {
        node = malloc( sizeof(struct tree) );
        node->data = data;
        node->left = node->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if( data > node->data ){
            node->right = insert(node->right, data);
        } else {
            node->left = insert(node->left, data);
        }  
    }

    return node;
}

void printtree(struct tree* node)
{
    if( node != NULL ){
        printf("%d\n", node->data);
        printtree(node->left);
        printtree(node->right);
    }   
} 

int main()
{
    struct tree *NODE = NULL;

    NODE = insert(NODE, 5);
    NODE = insert(NODE, 3);
    NODE = insert(NODE, 8);

    printtree(NODE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes it works now. Thanku by the way . There was problem with if statement but now it is fine ! :) And the way i was stating the if conditions "if( node )" works as well

Comment: `if(node)` works fine - it can be only less readable for others (for beginners, for teachers testing your knowlege ;) ) You can always mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: +1 This is a neat example. @user2456752 - `if (value)` really *should* only be used for integer T/F (not 0/0) tests. It's not good practice for `NULL` pointers, even if it is legal, and it makes code with heavy use of pointers harder to read.

Comment: @user2456752 Brett Hale is right pointers are hard to read especially `pointers to pointers` so learn to adding comments in code too :)

Answer (score 2):

The local variable: `struct tree* node;` is not initialized, so the `if (!node)` test will have undefined behavior. Unless you assign it something or use it to hold a malloc'd node, the expression in the `else` block tries to dereference an uninitialized pointer.

---

You should also get used to idea that a tree can be considered a 'recursive' structure, so any node *is* a tree, and the top-level tree is simply a node. There's no good reason for two separate types here.

Comment: i have changed the code but still it is giving segmentation fault.The "node" in place of "tree" was a typo error

Answer (score 1):

You are still making the error of passing NODE by value. If you want to modify it, you must use a pointer to that pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct t
{
    int data;
    struct t *left;
    struct t *right;
}tree;

tree* insert(tree **node, int data)
{
    if(!(*node))
    {
        *node=malloc(sizeof(tree));
        (*node)->data=data;
        (*node)->left=(*node)->right=NULL;
        return *node;
    }
    else
    {
        if(data>(*node)->data)
        {
            (*node)->right = insert(&((*node)->right),data);
            return *node;
        }
        else
        {
            (*node)->left = insert(&((*node)->left),data);
            return *node;
        }
    }
}

void printtree(tree *node)
{
    if(node)
    {
        printf("%d",node->data);
        printtree(node->left);
        printtree(node->right);
    }
}

void freeMemory(tree *node)
{
    if(node)
    {
        freeMemory(node->left);
        freeMemory(node->right);
        free(node);
    }
}

int main()
{
    tree *NODE = NULL;
    NODE= insert(&NODE,5);
    NODE= insert(&NODE,3);
    NODE= insert(&NODE,8);
    printtree(NODE);
    freeMemory(NODE);
    return 0;
}
```

Link: http://ideone.com/OpZWiC

Comment: He return node pointer as result and assign to NODE - he don't need to `pointer to pointer`. But he should do this with `pointer to pointer` because it is nicer ;)

Comment: Comment retracted ^_^, but he really should use `pointer to pointer` :)